# Moving a git repository up one hierarchy level

Tags: git, repository, hierarchy

Git beginner question:

I have a small private webproject which is versioned locally with msysgit. There is no exterior repository, as it's only for me, so i can bascially do whatever I want.

I've had this set up in the project directory, ie in "webroot".

Now a second directory had to be created, placed parallel to webroot. Let's call it assets.

So structure is now as follows:

```
\ project directory
----\webroot
----\assets
```

I'd love to include this new directory in the git repository, so that I'd also version changes to files stored there, but of course I can't use "git add ../assets". Neither am I inclined to create a new git project in project_directory, as this would loose all my previous commits.

So how do I go about moving the repository out of "webroot" up into "project_directory", while keeping my commits and then being able to include "assets"?

Comment: not exactly what you are asking, but you can create a branch an add assets into it.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

So, you want your git repo to look like this:

```
<projectdir>
    /.git
    /webroot
    /assets
```

To do this, you must move the existing files *in your repo* into a new `webroot` subdirectory.

```
cd <git repo root>
mkdir webroot
git mv <all your files> webroot
git commit --all -m "moved all existing files to new 'webroot' directory"
```

Then, on your local filesystem you want to relocate your clone one directory above where it is now:

```
cd <projectdir>
mv webroot/* .
rmdir webroot
```

Then you want to add the `assets` directory (and files) to the git repo:

```
git add assets
git commit -m "added assets to the repo"
```

Comment: Okay, apparently I've not given enough information. The repository already IS inside /projectdir/webroot/, as this is where it was originally created. Since the assets directory came to pass I'd prefer it if the repository was acting as if it was created in /projectdir/, which alas it was not. git mv will not let me move files outside the repository.

Comment: @Sorcy: I believe I understand what you want to do.  I updated my answer to clarify it.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the solution I was looking for. :)

Comment: I found hat this solution requires `mv webroot/.* .` as well, in order to move the repo and .gitignore files.

Comment: `git mv * webroot` won't work because bash wildcard * will be also substitued with webroot, making the command be `git mv webroot webroot`. Git will fail at that. The other folder that it had problems with was .git. So I had to use special bash env variable `GLOBIGNORE=webroot:.git` so that * won't be substitued with those two directories. Thanks to that I didn't have to make dozens of manual git mv - my directory has a lot of folders and files. I only had to move the .git folder manually.

Comment: Why `rmdir`? Doesn't `webroot` contain all the files you wanted to keep tracked?

Comment: This is the most correct and easiest way, if there are not too many files.
But instead of `mv webroot/* .; rmdir webroot`, use `mv webroot tmp; mv tmp/.git tmp/* .; rmdir tmp`.

Answer (score 24):

You can also just move your .git dir up one level and update your worktree.

```
cd projectdir
mv ./webroot/.git ./.git
git config core.worktree /absolute-path-to-project-dir
git add assets
git commit -m 'adding assets folder'
```

Not positive but I'm pretty sure the path to core.worktree has to be absolute.

Comment: Here's the order that worked for me. While I'm in the folder where I want to move the .git file:

`mv .git / ../`

Comment: I did this in a similar situation and I had to re-add files to the repo that had already been added when they were in the previous location. So essentially, I think I lost the git history for those files.

Answer (score 15):

I assume you meant to rewrite the history to contain all the files in all revisions *as if they had always been in a subdirectory webroot/ instead of in the root*

The git filter-branch manpage has the answer, here an improved version that rewrites all existing refs (branches) and tags:

```
time git filter-branch --index-filter 'git ls-files -s |
         sed "s-\t\"*-&webroot/-" |
         GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && 
     mv $GIT_INDEX_FILE.new $GIT_INDEX_FILE' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Care has been taken to make this an index-only operation so that the process will run fast even for big repos. Remember to (when satisfied) get rid of the original refs (.git/refs/original/*) and repack the repo to loose the obsolete tree objects.

Comment: Can you explain how to get rid of the original refs and repack the repo? Is it just GC or something else?

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thank you! For people who are confused, this operation should be done AFTER finishing [what Tim Henigan suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5408577/8301681).

Comment: I was confused at first as the code above creates a new `webroot/` folder inside the existing `webroot/` folder (so you'll have `project directory/webroot/webroot/`) and moves the contents of `project directory/webroot/` into `project directory/webroot/webroot/`. The trick is then to move all the contents of `project directory/` into `project directory/webroot/` and rename it as you wish.

Answer (score 5):

Your commits are not locally tied to the "webroot" folder they are stored within the git repo.

You could simply remove the webroot directory recheckout the repository in the new location "/project directory" add the assets directory and commit.

```
rm -Rf webroot
git clone path-to-repo
git add assets 
git commit -m "Added assets directory"
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command would rewrite your Git history. It would look like as if the content was in `webroot` all along. Usually rewriting history is troublesome if multiple people are working with a repo. Since you are working alone on it, it should be fine.

```
git filter-branch --index-filter '
    git read-tree --prefix="webroot/" $GIT_COMMIT && \
    git ls-files \
      | sed "s/\/.*//" \
      | sort \
      | uniq \
      | grep -v "^webroot" \
      | xargs -L1 git rm -r --cached > /dev/null'
```