# git 'fatal: pathspec did not match any files' after moving things around

Tags: git

I was trying to change the directory structure of my repository, as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408475/moving-a-git-repository-up-one-hierarchy-level) (following the accepted answer).  Things seemed fine after moving the directory, though it didn't recognise the files in their new location, and I got frustrated and just re-added everything. Now every file that I try to git-add comes back as 'fatal: pathspec FILE did not match any files'.

I honestly don't know how to diagnose the problem, and I don't want to blunder forward and screw things up even further. Any advice on how to proceed?

(git version 1.7.4.4 on OS X 10.8.2, if it's relevant)

Comment: If `git add FILE` is returning an error; what does `ls FILE` say?

Comment: The files aren't missing.  ls FILE says: FILE. :)

Answer (score 1):

Bah, this was my own stupid fault.  When it didn't recognise the files in their new location following the accepted answer in the linked question, I futzed around with the other answers to see if I could get it to work, and I think that I ended up changing the worktree directory to the old subdirectory by mistake.  Thus, it wasn't seeing anything in the root directory.  Modifying .git/config to set worktree to the current root of the repo fixed the issue.