# create a parent repo for an existing git repo

Tags: git, repository, git-submodules

I had an existing maven project `A` as a git repository. Later I realised that there were more related projects to be created. I have created a parent project and placed all the project `P` and placed `A` as a submodule to the maven project.

Now I want to make the same changes to be reflected to the git repository. But the repository root has changed. How should I go about to preserve the history of existing project and reflect the hierarchy as well in the project tree.

I don't want to create a new repo for `P` but reflect the same repo's root to point at `P`. If I move my `.git` directory from `A` to the `P` directory and commit the changes would that solve the purpose for me.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408475/moving-a-git-repository-up-one-hierarchy-level