# Moving root of git repo down one level in folder hierarchy while preserving history

Tags: git

So I have a git repo in this structure:

```
app
    app_one
    app_two
    app_three
```

The git repo root is in app. What I want is the root to simply be a folder containing app_one, app_two, app_three.

```
app_one
app_two
app_three
```

But the caveat is I want to do this while maintaining the current history of the file. Aka when I push this change to github, I don't want everything to show it was updated 3 seconds ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to do this while maintaining the current history of the file.

The easiest (and best IMO) way:

```
git mv app_one app_two app_three .
git commit
```

You will still have access to the entire history of changes for all files in every folder.

> I don't want everything to show it was updated 3 seconds ago.

This would require entirely rewriting the commit history with `git filter-branch` or `git rebase`. These are both dangerous if there are other developers who are working on existing branches. Also, they take a lot more time and effort. The above solution will work just fine for more cases.

For information about viewing history information across file moves see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743739/how-to-really-show-logs-of-renamed-files-with-git).

Comment: I would encourage this method be used^. However, if you are a confident repo surgeon, [it can be done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5446061/1695680)

Comment: In addition to this answer you might want to read about the concept of content history and how to view the history of a moved file [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743739/how-to-really-show-logs-of-renamed-files-with-git).

Comment: @lucash Thanks. Added that link to the answer proper.